# No me reconoce el metoo authenticate Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Usando la última versión me surge este pequeño inconveniente, en la documentación dice que hay que agregar este metodo al controlador para autenticarse(Esto en el Controlador Login)

```
public function authenticate()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Otra cosa yo para autenticarme uso es el username en vez del email y cambie los valores a :

```
public function authenticate(){
    if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->route('blog.index');
    }
}
```

Y al iniciar sesion me manda al index directamente, intente hacer un dd de $email y simplemente se loguea y va al index, como si obviara el authenticate

Tengo en mi LoginController

```
public function authenticate(){
    if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'activo' => 1],$remember)) {
        return redirect()->login('index');
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('debeconfirmar');
    }
}
```

Si el usuario ingresa sus datos bien, pero ademas confirmo su cuenta lo enviará al index es decir su cuenta esta activa, pero si el usuario ingreso su cuenta con los datos correctos pero aun no confirma el correo inmediatamente lo mandará a una pagina que le informará el proceso para confirmar su cuenta.

El problema esta que si el usuario ingresa los datos correctos y no este 'activo' el hace el login de igual forma y va a la pagina index

Answer (score 1):

Estás interpretando mal la documentación, el nombre del método `authenticate()` es solo un ejemplo, tú puedes llamar el método como quieras, lo que la documentación dice que debes tener en cuenta es utilizar preferiblemente el Facade Auth y el método `attempt()`, por defecto Laravel llama el método `login()` del trait AuthenticatesUsers:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
   // Authentication passed...
   return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}
```

El código de Laravel del método `attempt()`:

```
/**
 * Attempt to authenticate a user using the given credentials.
 *
 * @param  array  $credentials
 * @param  bool   $remember
 * @return bool
 */
public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false)
{
    $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember);

    $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

    // If an implementation of UserInterface was returned, we'll ask the provider
    // to validate the user against the given credentials, and if they are in
    // fact valid we'll log the users into the application and return true.
    if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)) {
        $this->login($user, $remember);

        return true;
    }

    // If the authentication attempt fails we will fire an event so that the user
    // may be notified of any suspicious attempts to access their account from
    // an unrecognized user. A developer may listen to this event as needed.
    $this->fireFailedEvent($user, $credentials);

    return false;
}
```

Más información en el código de Laravel: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L340

Comment: Ok, yo entiendo ya a lo que te refieres, ahora mi pregunta es como soluciono si por ejemplo en el metodo tambien digo que 'activo' => 1 para que pueda loguearse y siendo activo = 0 en mi user aun se loguea sin inconveniente, es decir me obvia el attempt

Comment: Muestra el código respectivo en la pregunta porque no entiendo lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Listo, ahí subí el codigo

Comment: Al parecer está bien tu código, sin embargo deberías hacer algo de debugging, revisa el código que genera el query: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php#L87